# Why Notifications remove from iOS notification centre automatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

When my app opens it removes all the notifications from the notification centre automatically. I don't wnat to remove all notifications until user remove them manually or tap on notification. To remove the badge number i write this line of code in my `delegate` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;` Is there any way to keep those notifications save?

Answer (score 1):

No, settings the `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber` will remove all push notifications.

Comment: i removed this line but still it is removing my notifications

Answer (score 1):

When you set the badge number to 0, a side-effect of this is that all remote notifications and local notifications are removed. But even if that was not the case, there is no API to remove only one specific remote notification - you have to remove them all.